# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apend'

Tags: python, stack

Por que ocorre este errp?

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apend'" with this code?

```
class Stack :
  def __init__(self) :
    self.items = []

  def push(self, item) :
    self.items.apend(item)

  def pop(self) :
    return self.items.pop()

  def isEmpty(self) :
    return (self.items == [])

  s = Stack()
  s.push(54)
  print s.pop()
```

Comment: Qual linguagem esta utilizando? é muito provável que seja  self.items.append(item) em vez de  self.items.apend(item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi apenas um erro de digitação. Vc esqueceu um 'p' em "append"

Troque

> `self.items.apend(item)`

por

> `self.items.append(item)`

Além disso, vc precisa recuar esse bloco para o escopo correto.

```
    s = Stack()   
    s.push(54)  
    print s.pop()
```

O código final ficaria assim

```
class Stack :
  def __init__(self) :
    self.items = []

  def push(self, item) :
    self.items.append(item)

  def pop(self) :
    return self.items.pop()

  def isEmpty(self) :
    return (self.items == [])


s = Stack()
s.push(54)
print(s.pop())
```

Veja funcionando online [aqui](https://repl.it/FxAd/0)

Comment: Caramba, obrigada, estava errado no site onde estou aprendendo...

Comment: Se o seu problema foi resolvido, considere [aceitar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a resposta clicando no 'v' verde ao lado esquerdo da pergunta.
Bons estudos.